# Does Part 135 allow single-engine night IFR operations in a turboprop?

Tags: faa-regulations, instrument-flight-rules, night-flying, far-135

Do the Part 135 rules allow single-engine turboprop night IFR Part-135 operations? If not, then all the night activities of current popular (and expensive) single-engine turboprops are by private or corporate owners and there are no commercial operations...!!!

I understand certain single engine turboprops are allowed to fly IFR at night for hire in EU, but I am not sure about it. Your input is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> Do the Part 135 rules allow single-engine turboprop night IFR Part-135 operations?

Yes, there is nothing preventing it provided [the pilot is night current](https://www.nbaa.org/ops/safety/in-flight-safety/night/Part135-Sect135-247.php) and the [airports are suitable for night operation](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/135.229).

You can find the [FAA's 135 general requirements here.](https://www.faa.gov/about/initiatives/atos/135_certification/general_req/)